# Laravel Session regenerates ID on refresh/ get another view

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-7, session-state

I'm using Laravel 7.30.6.

I'm trying to migrate my system, currently I use the `SESSION_DRIVER=file`, and I intend to use the database to be able to verify the active sessions with the respective logged users.
Using the file model, everything runs fine and normal. When switching to database, the following process occurs in the database:

- An id and the respective session information are generated in the database and saved.
- When logging in, this information is updated with the user_id, and the other information is maintained.
- Any action I take from there (going to another screen or reloading the page, for example) causes my current database line to be deleted, a new id is generated, without the user_id and I am automatically logged out.

In one of the screens I kept pressing f5, to see which id was generated through `session()->getId()` and it always generated a new one (This happens on all views).

Could it be that I'm forgetting something? Is something in the system blocking access?

I only use `Session::flush()` on loggin out from system, triggered by a button, so I'm not forcibly cleaning it.

My config/session.php

```
<?php

return [
'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'database'),
'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 120),
'expire_on_close' => false,
'encrypt' => false,
'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),
'connection' => null,
'table' => 'sessions',
'store' => null,
'lottery' => [2, 100],
 'cookie' => env(
        'SESSION_COOKIE',
        str_slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_session'
    ),
'path' => '/',
'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),
'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', false),
'http_only' => true,
'same_site' => null,
];
```

My .env contains `SESSION_DRIVER=database` and `SESSION_LIFETIME=120`, database mysql.

Table, model and controllers were created and are working normally when used via 'file'.

Regenerating the id forcibly with `session()->regenerate()`, doesn't change anything, even after logging in.

Also in the route I used the 'web' middleware, but nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem!
When generating the automatic table, using the laravel command itself, `php artisan session:table` it creates the `'payload'` column as `text`, however, in my case the size of it was being insufficient, causing the process to repeat itself whenever I reloaded or entered another page (because the path and values ​​were missing). Once that was done, I created it using a command of my own and placing the field as `LongText` (I didn't test if `MediumText` would be enough, but I already made it bigger since the table records and deletes data with a certain frequency, for me it won't change much).

Here my migration:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('sessions');
    Schema::create('sessions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('id')->unique();
        $table->unsignedInteger('user_id')->index('session_user_id_foreign')->nullable();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->string('ip_address', 45)->nullable();
        $table->text('user_agent')->nullable();
        $table->longText('payload');
        $table->integer('last_activity');
    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('sessions');
}
```